# Padding error with fitsSystemWindows on Kitkat

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use Kitkat's [transparent navigation bars](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#TranslucentBars) feature, and I get a weird effect:

Padding seems to be added to the bottom of my view when I add the [`fitsSystemWindows`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) attribute to `true`. This attribute is added to the first view so it doesn't align with the top and get displayed behind the status bar.

**This is what I want and expect:**
[image]

**But this is what I get:**
[image]

I tested it with `TextView`s as well, with the same result. I can't get it to work, I guess I'm missing something.

Below is my code:

File **`values-19/styles.xml`**:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor">
</style>
```

My layout file:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#800"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80f0"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#800f"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `android:fitsSystemWindows` on LinearLayout instead of ImageView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#800"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80f0"        
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#800f"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```